# Dynamically add Textbox to Window when checkbox is checked

Tags: java, swt

I'm just figuring out my way around SWT. I have a little problem that i cant seem to solve. I have a check-box in my window. When the check-box is checked, i would like add a multi-line, read-only, text box below it, lets say 200x200. I want the height of the window to increase to accommodate this text-box. When the check-box is unchecked I'd like the opposite to happen.

Could you help me with this? I can't find an example but maybe I'm not using the right keywords. Cheers.

--EDIT

the.duckman'ss answer was very helpful. I've managed to get it working to some extent. I'm adding a multi-line textbox 480px high. How do I automatically resize the window to accommodate the text box? When the user checks the checkbox, the textbox shows up but the height of the window doesn't increase to accommodate the textbox. My code is a little long so I've put it in PasteBin — http://pastebin.com/01RxKeEr

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking at the [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) to every beginner - that's probably the best place to go to with SWT questions.

[This snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet175.java) does exactly what you want.

**Edit**

Ooops, I ignored the second half of your question, sorry. Simply add this line to your listener:

```
shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip; it was very helpful. I've managed to get it working to some extent. I've made an edit to the original post. Could you have a look at it, please? Thanks.